# Group every N days

Tags: postgresql

Ive been searching for something like that using **PostgreSQL**, but havent found yet.

Lets suppose i have the following table:

```
id    order     amount    created_at
2     527837    10.0      2014-12-01T...
3     527838    50.0      2014-12-02T...
4     527839    30.0      2014-12-02T...
5     527840    40.0      2014-12-10T...
6     527841    80.0      2014-12-13T...
```

And i want to have a query that returns the sum of all amounts for each full week of 7 days (even if some day had no orders):

Example:

```
week                    total_amount
Dec/01 - Dec/07         90.0
Dec/08 - Dec/15         120.0
Dec/16 - Dec/23         0.0
//...and so on until current date
```

Also, lets suppose, that January has 30 days, and February has 28 days, i want the weeks to be grouped like that:

- Jan/01-Jan/08
- Jan/09-Jan/16
- Jan/17-Jan/24
- Jan/25-Feb/02 (theres no problem on crossing months)
- Feb/03-Feb/10

What is the best way to do this?

***EDIT 1:***

I have found a way to build a query to generate a temporary table with the days i need for my grouping, i just having dificult grouping this and joining it with my original table...

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(generate_series, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "day" FROM generate_series('2013-06-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                          '2015-06-01 00:00'::timestamp, '1 Day'))
```

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Sure, why not?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45dc6/1

Answer (score 3):

```
select date_trunc('week', created_At),date_trunc('week', created_At)+ INTERVAL '6' DAY,
    SUM(amount) 
from t
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', created_At)
ORDER BY MIN(created_At);
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/87ed1/7)

Comment: Hi Mihai,

This set of data returned in your query does not include empty days. I need to include these empty days also, thats why i was thinking about to use a generated temporary tables only with the days.

Comment: @RenatoAlves You want them just visually since they dont do anything?

Comment: @RenatoAlves Here is how you can generate an interval and JOIN on your table.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/76c29/15

Comment: Hum, nice, there is a way to do it without creating the days table? I mean, using it like a subquery in the Join

Comment: @RenatoAlves This is beyond my knowledge,it might be.